# Are "modules over an additive group" a thing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, terminology, definition

Googling around, the only notion of "module over a group $G$" I was able to find was [here](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eschmidt/Neukirch-en/Neukirch_cft_02_may15.pdf), where $G$ is a *multiplicative* group but acts on an *additive* group. But I'm curious about another notion, which I'll call a **module over an additive group**. I'll define the structure and then say why I think it's interesting. My question is, does this structure appear naturally in any existing areas of math, and is it studied? Is there a correct name for it?

---

**Definition:**

Let $V$ and $S$ be additive abelian groups, thought of as "vectors" and "scalars" respectively. An **additive $S$-module over $V$** is the triple $(V,S,\cdot)$, where $\cdot$ is a map from $S\times V\to V$ satisfying the *second and third* properties below. For all $s,t\in S$ and all $v,u\in V$:

- $\require{cancel} \cancel{(st)v=s(tv)}$
- $(s + t)v = sv + tv$
- $s(v + u) = sv + su$
- $\require{cancel} \cancel{1v=v}$

The first condition (crossed out) is not required, and in fact makes no sense because $st$ is not defined. The fourth condition (also crossed out) is also not required, and also makes no sense because $S$ is only an additive group and does not necessarily have an element called $1$. But I put these there to be suggestive. If $S=V$, then the first condition makes sense, and with it, the resulting structure is precisely the definition of a ring (without unity). If $S$ happens to have more structure and indeed has a $1$ element, it would be natural to include the fourth axiom.

**Motivation:**

For one thing, this seems to be a natural generalization of modules to the simplest possible setting of two groups. But more importantly, once we define abelian groups and then the simple structure above, we basically get rings, modules, and algebras by applying the same procedure recursively and including the crossed-out conditions when they make sense.

E.g., the above structure when $S=V$ is a non-associative ring, and with the (very natural) first condition, a ring. Then applying the same construction to a ring over an abelian group gives a left-module over a ring without unity. If the ring has a unity element, then the fourth condition is natural, and with it, we get a true left-module. The same construction with a commutative ring over a ring *almost* gives an algebra; we just need the other condition $s(vu)=(sv)u=v(su)$.

So it seems this structure is basic, natural, and also unifying.

Comment: Is this not just a group action on the endomorphisms of $V$?

Comment: You can rephrase your definition by saying that the structure is given by a group morphism $S\to \operatorname{End}_\mathbb{Z}(V)$, instead of the usual ring morphism.

Comment: Your second and third conditions make sense more generally, for a map $S\times V\to X$, where $S,V,X$ are three additive abelian groups. That's just a bilinear map, and your modules are the special case where $X=V$. Note that the general ntion is symmetric between $S$ and $V$.